# Gradle dependency to project in buildscript

Tags: gradle

Trying to get my head around if it is possible to use Tasks from other projects in Gradle. Let's say ProjectB is a project with src/main/groovy containing com.MyTask, having parent ProjectA

In build.gradle in ProjectC, also having parent ProjectA:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies{
        project(':ProjectB')
    }
}
```

That seems to be legit, because introdusing a typo in "project(:'ProjectB')" fails hard. What also fails is introducing this line:

```
import com.MyTask
```

Is project-references not valid in buildscript closure? Also tried moving com.MyTask to buildSrc/src/main/groovy with the same amount of success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution which worked for me was to make "com.MyTask" available both at configurationtime and in sources.
ProjectA(the parent) got this added to buildSrc/build.gradle's sourceSets:

```
sourceSets{
    main{
        groovy{
            srcDir 'ProjectB/src/main/groovy'
        }
    }
}
```

Now ProjectC and all other projects can use MyTask. At the same time it is bundled with the final jar of ProjectB.

The issue has also been discussed thoroughly between between Adam Murdoch, Luke Daley and Steve Ebersole: http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/buildSrc-as-a-regular-project-td5677255.html

Edit: It was smarter manipulating parent buildSrc than the standalone project. That way IntelliJ is happy-go-lucky.

Comment: "IntelliJ did not like it" haha, no I bet it didnt.

Comment: Haha! Sorry for editing the answer just as you commented @mike-rylander !

Comment: Thanks for figuring out how to make IntelliJ happy.

Answer (score 0):

From Gradle documentation [15.4. Adding dependencies to a task](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html):

Example 15.13. Adding dependency on task from another project

```
build.gradle

project('projectA') {
    task taskX(dependsOn: ':projectB:taskY') << {
        println 'taskX'
    }
}

project('projectB') {
    task taskY << {
        println 'taskY'
    }
}
```

Comment: Good call! But I might not have stated the problem clear enough. It is not defined tasks that I want to use, it is Tasks created on the classpath. For example exporting ProjectC to mavenLocal() and importing it in ProjectB in buildscript works fine. Then the MyTask is available.

Comment: Also tried to define a "MyTask" at ProjectC and dependOn that in ProjectB, but I was not able to as "MyTask" is in src/main/gradle and not in buildSrc/src/main/gradle.

Comment: @OleChristianLangfjæran have you looked at ch 15.2? have you tried `tasks.getByPath('MyTask')`

Comment: good tip again, but didn't work. The reason being that tasks are not available at configurationtime since I'm building a standalone project containing the Task. The solution was to edit the standalone projects sourceSets. Found out later that this problem has been discussed thoroughly between Adam Murdoch, Luke Daley  and Steve Ebersole: http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/buildSrc-as-a-regular-project-td5677255.html